# emacs - reassign "start text selection" key

Tags: emacs

I've been tweaking tmux keys and settled on Ctrl-Space as my prefix instead of the default Ctrl-b.

I'm also using emacs keys, so Ctrl+Space is also the start-text-selection key. But now that I'm using it as the prefix key, how can I bind start selection key to something else?

Answer (score 0):

It *is* bound to something else. What happens if you press `S-right` (that is SHIFT+right arrow key) over some text?